# how to install rtab map in ROS indigo

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am using ROS indigo.I want to create a 3D map of my lab using hand held kinect and I read that rtab map is the best option.But my ROS did not have rtab map package.Someone please help me to install rtab  map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223793/how-to-install-rtab-map-in-ros-indigo/) by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Binaries:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rtabmap ros-indigo-rtabmap-ros
```

If you want to build the latest version from source, visit the [rtabmap_ros's GitHub page](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap_ros) (see installation instructions at the bottom of the page).

For an example of hand-held mapping with a Kinect, checkout this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping).

**EDIT** (from questions in comments)

You can export the cloud in PLY, PCD or OBJ (See File->"Export clouds" in main window). These formats can be loaded in [MeshLab](http://sourceforge.net/projects/meshlab/), where you can export them in X3D or WRL.

If you don't use "--delete_db_on_start" when launching the launch file, the rtabmap.db file contains all sessions. If there are no loop closures between the sessions, you will only see the latest one when starting a new session. If you want one session per database, you have to manually copy `~/.ros/rtabmap.db` between the sessions. Note that for hand-held mapping with RTAB-Map, you don't even need ROS, and the [standalone version is easier to use to create/save multiple databases](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Kinect-mapping) (just type `$ rtabmap` to use the standalone).

To view all sessions contained in a database, you can open it with `$ rtabmap-databaseViewer ~/.ros/rtabmap.db`. Then show the Graph view panel and set from which node the graph is optimized. Depending on which node the map is optimized, a different scanning session may appear. You can then generate the point cloud associated with the current graph (File->export).

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-01-12**:
thank you sir
I used this command and installed rtabmap.Before doing 3D mapping with real kinect I tried it with turtlebot package.I used the commands
1.`roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch`
2.`roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch`
but it says no openni2 devices connected.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-01-12**:
Look at section 5 of this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/MappingAndNavigationOnTurtlebot). If Turtlebot has a Kinect, you should do `$ export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=kinect` before launching the nodes.

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-01-14**:
Thank you sir
I started working with real kinect.And I got 3D map using rtabmap.I got a folder rtabmap.db in ~/.ros folder.But this folder is saving my current scan data.I am losing my previous scan data on every scan.Sir I also want to know is it possible to convert this .db file to .wrl format.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-01-14**:
Updated the answer for these questions.

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-01-19**:
Thank you sir...It worked for me.I want to convert the pointcloud to laser scan and i used freenect to collect the kinect data.Then I used the command `rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/camera/depth/image_raw` .But it doesnt work.There were no data under the topic /scan.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-01-21**:
if you started `freenect.launch` with `depth_registered:=true`, you should use `/camera/depth_registered/image_raw`

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-01-22**:
I did it...it's working..thank you.

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-01-25**:
sir..I used hecto_slam to build a 2D map from kinect data.I used the command `roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch`and  getting "[ WARN] [1453709644.419967908]: No transform between frames /map and scanmatcher_frame available after 20.001889 seconds of waiting. This warning only".Plz help me

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-01-27**:
It may be better to as a new question about hector_slam for this specific problem. Note that rtabmap can provide a 2D map on /grid_map output topic if its input scan topic is set.

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-01-28**:
Ok.I have posted a new question :)  [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/225333/problem-with-hector_slam/)